# toggle a div below changes the width of a clicked div

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div id='wrapp'>
    <div id='left'>LEFT</div>
    <div id='right'>
        <div id='rightTop'>rightTop</div>
        <div id='rightBottom'>rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom rightBottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapp{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#left{
    display:table-cell;
    width:30px;
    padding-left:0.5%;
    background:green;
}
#right{
    display:table-cell;
    background:blue;
}
#rightTop{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto 2px auto;
    background:yellow;
    line-height:27px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#rightBottom{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto 25px auto;
    background:#e1e1e1; 
    text-align:justify;
}
```

js

```
$('#rightTop').click(function(){
    $('#rightBottom').toggle();
});
```

Why click on `#rightTop` (toggle the div bellow) changes the width of `#rightTop` for a few pixels?

This happens only in Chrome, not in Firefox.

I tried to reproduce the problem using jsfiddle - but it's ok there, there is no width changes. (here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x8BtB/1/)).

Here is a [**live example**](http://mc.net46.net/lm/index.php) - if someone could click on header (named `KLANICA`) and check why the header changes its width in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Update CSS to the following for resolution:

```
.ch #divR {
display: table-cell;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 75%;
}

.ch #divL {
display: table-cell;
width: 25%;
padding-left: 0.5%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need table and not block display. If I change to block all design will be off.

Comment: .ch #divR {
display: table-cell;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 723px;
}

Comment: Please stop to answer without solution. I's not the solution to change the entire site's layout (table should remain 100% width).

Comment: There is no width currently set on #divR and there is a set width on #divL the container is still 100%. Perhaps try changing #divL to 25% width and #divR to 75% width and then add the table-layout:fixed to #divR

Comment: No, left cell should be 300 px fixed.